# "loading" message doesn't display while processing a copy function

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

In my Flask application I need to show a "waiting" div while processing a file copy. It seemed to me a trivial task, so I wrote:

**server side:**

```
@cotg.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def startCopy():
    source = request.form.getlist('sourcedisk[]')
    dest= request.form.getlist('destdisk[]')
    action_Copy()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**template side:**

```
 $(document).ready(   
        function () {
        $("#wait").hide();  
        $('#startcopy').submit(function(event){
            var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (c == true) {
                $("#wait").show();
                }
            return c; 
        });
});
```

but it simply doesn't work as expected. The page holds until the `action_Copy()` function ends without displaying the `#wait` div.

Comment: try using `document.getElementById("wait").style.display = 'none';` and `document.getElementById("wait").style.display = 'block';`

Comment: The problem is not in the jQuery part. That is working. The problem is that the page waits the execution of all the function action_Copy() before showing the "wait" div, instead of showing it before, as it should.

Comment: you have put the "show wait syntax" inside of submit, you should execute the `startcopy()` function inside of `if (c == true) {}`

Comment: Is that typo `$("wait").hide();` ?

Comment: @Ankush, that seems to be the trick, but startcopy is bind to the submit event. How can I put inside the "if"?

Comment: I have put the "show wait syntax" inside the "if (c == true) {}" but it is the same. The "wait" div gets rendered only when I render the page, after the action_Copy() function in the server, so I suspect something's wrong on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your "#startcopy" submit event does but the logic here is

1. get `YES` from the `confirm` box
2. show the `#wait div`
3. invoke the `submit` method
4. hide the `#wait div`

try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (c == true) {
        $("#wait").show();
        $('#startcopy').submit(function(event){
            $("#wait").hide();
        }
        return c;
    }
});
```